# Can diesel tanker lorries / trucks run off the fuel they are carrying? Or do they need to stop at a gas station to fill up?

Tags: diesel, truck

So this is a question that's been keeping me awake at night. Tankers sometimes carry diesel fuel. To refuel do they:

1. Stop at a gas station and fill up?
2. Stop at the side of the road and move diesel from the tanker to their truck's tank?
3. Or do they have a line going directly from the diesel tank they are hauling directly into the engine?

Comment: The fuel likely doesn’t belong to the company delivering it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tractor's fuel tanks are filled in the same way as other non-tanker hauling tractors.  At a fuel depot.  Assuming that the tanker was carrying the correct type of fuel (i.e. diesel) it is conceivable that some piping contraption might be rigged up to fill the tractor's tanks from the tanker but that would be highly dangerous and likely illegal.  The chances for a spill are great and there is a lack of appropriate safety equipment that you normally have at a fuel depot.

So in answer to your question, #1 is what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was hoping it was 3. The ultimate getaway vehical, with acid for blood, you don't dare kill it.